# How can I make class structures out of my Json request?

Tags: java

I have this Json Request:

```
{
    info: { ... },
    values: {
      settings: {
         data: [{ ... }],
         functions: [{ ... }]
      
     }
   }
}
```

What is the best way to make an object out of it? One object per field or I can make a inner static class?

this is what ihave done so far:

```
Class Info {
    ...
}

Class Value {
   private Settings settings;
}

Class Settings {
   private List<Data> data;
   private List<Function> functions;
}
```

Comment: `settings` is a JSON object and not an array

Comment: ah yah.. edited

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your solution but I would say the whole topic as widely opinion-based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd create classes little by little, by reading the json structure.  But you can actually use your own method.
I've found this, which is another solution:

> http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

using Gson Annotation style, so that it won't create any additionalProperties field.
But as I said, this is **a** solution.